# Hide button's border when click

Tags: vb.net

In my program, when I clicked the "question mark button" it shows another form as shown in the image below. But the button's border is shown, how can I make it transparent?
[image]

Comment: [Owner-draw button](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3620/Owner-draw-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
testButton.TabStop = false
testButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
testButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
testButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White
testButton.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.White
testButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.White
testButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White
```

[Refer this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/164861/How-to-remove-border-of-a-Standard-Button-in-Win-f)

Comment: Thank you very much. The `testButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White` did the job :)

Comment: That's not fixing the problem . You asked how to remove it not change the color.

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood my question

Answer (score 4):

The only way to alter the border of a 'standard' button is to draw it yourself. 
This would also be the best way to overcome your problems with the Image. Or you can set the flat appearance as below...

```
 Me.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
```

You can do this on the load event if you want.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, worked for me. The other 'answer' bypasses the problem and does not fix it.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ I would agree :)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue :

- "BorderSize = 0" couldn't solve
- Setting BorderColor to a solid brush
  was not applicable since my BackGround was a custom bitmap. The
  BorderColor would have been visible anyway.

Trying to "root cause" the annoying border though : the border is due to the focus still being somehow set on the button while the DialogBox is displayed.

Do you follow me ?...

So all you have to do is move the focus away... before opening your DialogBox. Example below :

```
TextBox1.focus()
Dim result As DialogResult = frmMyDialog.ShowDialog(Me)
```

That did the trick for me ;)

HTH

Mickael Delorme

---

Merry X-Mas, Pepita !